# Serve and upload blobs using the same URL

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, blobstore

I am using the python version of Google AppEngine. I want to be able to be able to serve and upload blobs from/into the blobstore using the same URL. As an example, lets say a user can upload a display picture for himself. A GET request to `/user/USERNAME/avatar` will return the image, whilst a POST request to the same URL will set it.

[AFAIK, this isn't possible, as each action requires a different kind of handler.](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Complete_Sample_App)

Sure, I could just use two handlers, but that's a kludge, and I have OCD when it comes to these things.

Comment: Is using the same URL more important to you than using the Blobstore API?  This is fairly easily accomplished if you're willing to store the image in the datastore instead of in Blobstore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible, not because of handler 'kinds' - these are just convenience subclasses that do some extra work for you - but because uploads have to be to a specific, runtime-generated URL.